# Combining One Column from Excel Worksheets

Tags: python, excel

I have a couple thousand excel worksheets. Each worksheet has column A populated, up to about 40 rows. I want to make one master worksheet that has the information from each worksheet in a different column. For instance, say I have 1000 worksheets I want to combine, for the master worksheet, column A would be populated by column A in worksheet#1/1000, column B would be populated by column A in worksheet#2/1000, column C would be populated by column A worksheet#3/1000, etc.

These columns do not have a common header.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  VBA seems appropriate.

Comment: @E.Trauger I don't exactly know how to write the code for this.

Comment: Well, Stackoverflow is not a website where you go to get people to write code for you.  Try something yourself before asking someone to write a macro for you.  Use Google

Comment: Are all these worksheets in the same workbook (i.e. excel file)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, all worksheets are in same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

First make a 'Master' sheet as sheet 1.  Then make a Macro to loop through each sheet, copy the entire first column, and paste in the first empty column in row 1.  Loop until you exhaust the sheets.  We can help you more if you show some of your code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This /should/ do it. I haven't tested it, but it should be simple enough to fix from here

```
import itertools
import openpyxl as px

infile = px.load_workbook('path/to/input')
outsheet = wb.get_shee_by_name(wb.sheetnames[0])

for col,sheet in zip(itertools.count(1), (infile.get_sheet_by_name(sname) for sname in infile.sheetnames)):
    for r,cell in enumerate((r for _col in sheet.columns for r in _col), 1):
        sheet.cell(row=r, col=col).value = cell.value

infile.save('path/to/output')
```